# Cannot resolve constructor ArrayAdapter(android.Content.Context, int, java.util.ArrayList<MyObject>

Tags: java, android

Hello I am getting this error I can't fix it, anyone know where this error comes from, I get this error very often

> error type: 'SlideImagesAdapter(android.content.Context, java.util.List<com.khuongviettai.ecommerce.utils.SlidePhoto>)' in 'com.khuongviettai.ecommerce.adapter.SlideImagesAdapter' cannot be applied to '(com.khuongviettai.ecommerce.fragment.HomeFragment, java.util.List<com.khuongviettai.ecommerce.utils.SlidePhoto>)'

SideImageAdapter

```java
public class SlideImagesAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

    private Context context;
    private List<SlidePhoto> slidePhotoList;

    public SlideImagesAdapter(Context context, List<SlidePhoto> slidePhotoList) {
        this.context = context;
        this.slidePhotoList = slidePhotoList;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(@NonNull ViewGroup container, int position) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(container.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.slide_images, container, false);
        ImageView imageView = view.findViewById(R.id.iv_slide_img);
        SlidePhoto slidePhoto = slidePhotoList.get(position);
        if (slidePhoto != null){
            // using load => loading img at local
            Glide.with(context).load(slidePhoto.getImgID()).into(imageView);
        }
        // add to viewGroup
        container.addView(view);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        if(slidePhotoList != null) {
            return slidePhotoList.size();
        }
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(@NonNull View view, @NonNull Object object) {
        return view == object;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(@NonNull ViewGroup container, int position, @NonNull Object object) {
        // remove view
        container.removeView((View) object);
    }
}
```

SlidePhoto

```java
public class SlidePhoto {
    private int imgID;

    public SlidePhoto(int imgID) {
        this.imgID = imgID;
    }

    public int getImgID() {
        return imgID;
    }

    public void setImgID(int imgID) {
        this.imgID = imgID;
    }
}
```

HomeFragment

```java
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

    private View view;
    private ViewPager vpg_homeFM_img;
    private CircleIndicator indicator_home_img;
    private SlideImagesAdapter slideImagesAdapter;


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
        vpg_homeFM_img = view.findViewById(R.id.vpg_homeFM_img);
        indicator_home_img = view.findViewById(R.id.indicator_home_img);
        slideImagesAdapter = new SlideImagesAdapter(this, getListSlidePhoto());
        vpg_homeFM_img.setAdapter(slideImagesAdapter);
        indicator_home_img.setViewPager(vpg_homeFM_img);
        slideImagesAdapter.registerDataSetObserver(indicator_home_img.getDataSetObserver());
        return view;
    }
    private List<SlidePhoto> getListSlidePhoto() {
        List<SlidePhoto> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(new SlidePhoto(R.drawable.swiper1));
        list.add(new SlidePhoto(R.drawable.swiper2));
        list.add(new SlidePhoto(R.drawable.swiper3));
        return list;
    }
}
```

[image: img error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace:

```java
slideImagesAdapter = new SlideImagesAdapter(this, getListSlidePhoto());
```

with:

```
slideImagesAdapter = new SlideImagesAdapter(requireContext(), getListSlidePhoto());
```

...as a `Fragment` is not a `Context`.

Comment: thanks, i fixed it, i declared wrong between layout and java file i used viewpager2 but java file i declared viewpager.